# How to add a button that floats over a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a TableView that displays a list of posts. I would like to add a button that floats over the TableView and the button doesn't move as the user scrolling through the posts. The button will enable a user to post. How can I implement this? I can't seem to add a superview to my tableview.

Google Plus app does something similar, but if you don't have the app, the [official website](http://plus.google.com) also presents this behavior. The button is located on the bottom left.

Thanks!

Comment: Floating Action Button ist not an Apple UI Pattern... just saying

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to handle this without needing to lose the table view controller.

### Use a container view for the table view controller

If you are using a storyboard, setup a view controller with the button and a container view. In that container view, have the table view controller. You can use delegation, notifications, or key value observing to keep the two view controller in sync.

### Add the button to the window instead of the table view controller

If you just want the button to simply float over the table view, then you can add the button to the window instead of the view. This has to be done at runtime.

Comment: Another option is to add the button as a subview to the table view, and update it's transform on `scrollViewDidScroll:`

Comment: This way is bad, because in this case button will "dancing", while tableView will scrolling

Comment: @Igor scrollViewDidScroll gets called before rendering whenever the content offset changes. If your math is correct, you will never see the view "dancing", if you do, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**The better way** is to create `UIViewController` (not `UITableViewController`) and add to it `UITableView` and `UIButton`. In this case you can adjust all views in Storyboard and set proper constraints.

When we use `UIViewController` and have adding tableView and button, **we can do most of interface settings in InterfaceBuilder**.

You can, of course, add button to `UINavigationController` view, if `UITableViewController` embed in, or to `keyWindow` but this is worse way .

Comment: Using a TableViewController has some advantages over a ViewController with a tableView, for example, you can't have a static table without a TableViewController. Using a container to contain the TableViewController is a better idea. Adding it to the nav controller or the window are bad ideas.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, I disagree with you. When we use `UIViewController` and have adding tableView and button, we can do most of interface settings in `InterfaceBuilder`. It will be visually and conveniently to adjust for different screen sizes. If you need tableView with static cells, you can add container view and embed in it `UITableViewConrtoller`. Again, most of setting will done in `InterfaceBuilder`. The way, that you suggest is bad (adjust button in scrollViewDidScroll:), because in this case button will "dancing", while tableView will scrolling.

Comment: `UITableViewController` has advantages in one case - if you use ONLY `UITableView` without adding another subviews to it. Adding of subviews creates inconvenience and bugs, because `UITableViewController`is not intended for this (think, why you can't add subview to UITableView in IB?).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a custom header view with the button, and use that view for your table's `viewForHeaderInSection`. This way, you can keep your controller as a `UITableViewController` rather than `UIViewController`, and it will remain on top as the user scrolls.

Note that you'll need to adapt your data source/delegate logic if your table has multiple sections, as each section has a deader.

Comment: The button could be added to the first (or multiple, if desired) section header if that is the case

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  Apparently, there is a bug in Interface Builder that does not allow placing a UIButton, or UIView above UITableView.  The workaround is to drag a button or view into Document Outline and place it at the very bottom of the scene.  After doing so, you can place that button in front of the UITableView.

Finally, the button or image won't appear until adding Autolayout Constraints.  After doing so the button or image will appear to float over the table and remain fixed as the user scrolls.

Thanks!